# Building a password algorithm, with password hashing

Tags: python, password-encryption, password-hash, password-generator

**Questions/Problem**

I am attempting to make a password generator that will hash the password after displayed to the user and stores it in a file that it makes the first time it is ran. I am not sure how to go about doing this or how to do this. I tested out a few password generators and ended up going with the one shown below. So far I have tried to hash with SH 256 and was unable to get that to work, along with bcrypt.

**Code**

```
from random import choice, randint
import string

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.hexdigits + string.punctuation + string.octdigits

password = "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(25,100)))

print(password)
```

Comment: `from hashlib import sha256`, then `sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()`.

Comment: *unable to get that to work* - Please be more specific. What's the result? Any errors? Result different from what you expected?

Comment: My bad, I meant that I got no results as in nothing. Even after debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example using `hmac` with `sha256`

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import string
from random import choice, randint

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.hexdigits + string.punctuation + string.octdigits

password = "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(25, 100)))

print(password)

SECRET = 'this is my secret'


def hash_password(pw):
    hashed_password = hmac.new(
        SECRET.encode(),
        msg=pw.encode(),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest().upper()
    return hashed_password


password_file = 'test.password'
with open(password_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(hash_password(password))

user_supplied = input('Enter the password supplied: ')

with open(password_file, 'r') as f:
    print(f"Does match? {f.read() == hash_password(user_supplied)}")
```

Here is an example run

```
bXFREVkOJ~PDUBEfSkUcK[W6s~yDcDzdCi*SjxOc6T79a5[7s\P0i|)yh#'rK6nzB@CEDX1T7Umc-OOEi
Enter the password supplied: bXFREVkOJ~PDUBEfSkUcK[W6s~yDcDzdCi*SjxOc6T79a5[7s\P0i|)yh#'rK6nzB@CEDX1T7Umc-OOEi
Does match? True
```

Comment: Thank You So much for that working example, Would it be ok if I used some of this code for my project?

Comment: Feel free to use the code and your welcome. Please accept the answer if this works for you

Comment: When the code is run it gives you a password, if i am not mistaken. how is this hashed and secured in the file called test.password. I am new to hashing and have little knowledge.

Comment: The password is printed.  The value stored in the file is an `hmac-sha256` hashed string of the password.  The value stored in the file is the secure hash.  The printed value is just substituting for a user inputted password

Answer (score 0):

this small example i hope it be useful

```
import random
import string
from random import choice, randint

def get_random_string(length):

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + 
string.digits + string.hexdigits + string.punctuation + string.octdigits

result_str = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))
print("the hasheds password is:", result_str)

get_random_string(8)
get_random_string(8)
```

Comment: also you can open an file and save the result inside it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
import hashlib
import bcrypt
import base64
import string
from random import choice


def encrypt_password(password):
    password = password.encode('utf-8')
    if len(password) > 72:
        password = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(password).digest())
    return bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('ascii') # 60 characters long

def verify_password(password, encrypted_password):
    hashed = encrypted_password.encode('ascii')
    password = password.encode('utf-8')
    if len(password) > 72:
        password = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(password).digest())
    return bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed)

def generate_password(length=16, chars=string.ascii_letters+string.digits+string.punctuation):
    return ''.join([ choice(chars) for i in range(length) ])


password = generate_password()
encrypted_password = encrypt_password(password)
print(password, encrypted_password)
print(verify_password(password, encrypted_password))
```

Prints:

```
SL6X95n4rk<[VHK_ $2b$12$q6DfXygpSFW3JI9EQXJmm.wy8ZhhJiJ6mK907bHJXnv8XQdEe9ofG
True
```